# Is there an in-memory key/value store that can notify an external entity of a change?

Tags: memcached, couchdb, key-value-store

I have read about in-memory key/value stores but have never actually utilized one.  The first that come to my uneducated mind are CouchDB and memcached (I know CouchDB isn't necessarily in-memory, but is often used as such).

I am looking for one of these in-memory stores that support basic scripting, such that I could notify an external entity (through a RESTful API) of a change.  Some preliminary research reveals that CouchDB supports something called [Change Notifications](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html)

Memcached does not seem to support this type of feature, and is a more general storage-only service (again, my ignorance may shine through here).

Does anyone have any experience doing this?  Any words of wisdom for potential pitfalls or headaches? Is there some other software I didn't list that would support these features?

Answer (score 2):

[membase](http://www.membase.org/) implements the memcached [tap protocol](http://wiki.membase.org/display/membase/TAP+Protocol) to stream out all mutations as they occur.  We build a lot of stuff on top of that (replication is a use case).

Comment: ohh, that sounds promising.  Do you use the membase client that is mentioned in the linked page?  I notice the discussion gets into low level binary messages, was curious how easy the client was to use.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be the same Dustin as the one mentioned a few times on the membase site, would you? :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit biased, but I conceived of the tap thing way back when I was only doing memcached stuff to solve problems like you just mentioned.  If you're talking about the python client there, I wrote that one and do use it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about mounting RAM as disk and starting couchdb with that as data dir?

You can mount a ram disk as:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/couchdb
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs -o size=2G /tmp/couchdb
```

And change the couchdb configuration file to store the data in that directory.

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = /tmp/couchdb
view_index_dir = /tmp/couchdb
```

Start couchdb and relax!

Comment: I don't see anything in the answer about the notification component of my question.  How would I get notified of a change to data?

Comment: You can use CouchDB's [Change notification](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html).